# Assign a new name to a Gradle dependency

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle script that has a dependency on a Jar from another project.  I'd like to be able to change the name of the dependency once it has been downloaded so that other tasks pick up the new name.

For example, if I have the following reference:

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.example:old-name:1.2.3"
}
```

I'd like this jar to be visible elsewhere as `new-name-1.2.3.jar` so that, for example, the `distZip` task from the `application` plugin adds the file with the new name to the library directory rather than the old name.  All other dependencies should keep their existing names.

Is there a way to achieve this with Gradle?